# Python, Tensorflow(Input_shape change error)-Input to reshape is a tensor with 1474560 values, but the requested shape has 98304

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm Training the model using Python and Tensorflow 1.15.

## Problem

The code I used is a CRNN model that recognizes letters in an image, which is written as input_shape = (width, height, 1).
For your information, we are proceeding with gray scale after resizing the image to (32,256).

```
def crop_words2(word, height, width, grayscale=True):
    if grayscale:
        word = cv2.cvtColor(word, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        word = cv2.normalize(word, word, alpha=0, beta=255, norm_type=cv2.NORM_MINMAX)
        word = word[:,:,None]

    word = word.astype(np.float32)
    tmp_word = word[:,:width,:]
    word = np.zeros([height, width, tmp_word.shape[2]])

    word[:,slice(0, tmp_word.shape[1]), :] = tmp_word

    word = word[:,:256]
    
    
    return word

def generate(self, train=True):
        gt_util = self.gt_util
            
        kor = self.kor
        batch_size = self.batch_size
        width, height = self.input_size
        max_string_len = self.max_string_len
        concatenate = self.concatenate
        num_input_channels = 1 if self.grayscale else 3
        
        inputs = []
        targets = []
        
        np.random.seed(1337)
        i = gt_util.num_samples
        while True:
            while len(targets) < batch_size:
                if i == gt_util.num_samples:
                    idxs = np.arange(gt_util.num_samples)
                    np.random.shuffle(idxs)
                    i = 0
                idx = idxs[i]
                i += 1
                
                img_name = gt_util.image_names[idx]
                img_path = os.path.join(gt_util.image_path, img_name)
                img = cv2.imread(img_path)
                

                texts = np.copy(gt_util.text[idx])
                words = [crop_words2(img, 32, 256, True)]
                
                inputs.extend(words)
                targets.extend([texts])
            
            source_str = np.array(targets[:batch_size])
            
            images = np.ones([batch_size, width, height, num_input_channels])
            labels = -np.ones([batch_size, max_string_len])
            input_length = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
            label_length = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
            
            for j in range(batch_size):
                images[j] = inputs[j].transpose(1,0,2)
                input_length[j,0] = max_string_len
                label_length[j,0] = len(source_str[j])
                for k, c in enumerate(source_str[j][:max_string_len]):
                    if not c in kor or c == '_':

                        labels[j][k] = kor.index(' ')
                    else:
                        labels[j][k] = kor.index(c)
            
            inputs_dict = {
                'image_input': images,
                'label_input': labels,
                'input_length': input_length, # used by ctc
                'label_length': label_length, # used by ctc
                'source_str': source_str, # used for visualization only
            }
            outputs_dict = {'ctc': np.zeros([batch_size])}  # dummy
            yield inputs_dict, outputs_dict
            
            inputs = inputs[batch_size:]
            targets = targets[batch_size:]
```

```
input_width = 256
input_height = 32
batch_size = 32
input_shape = (input_width, input_height, 1)

model, model_pred = CRNN(input_shape, len(kor))
experiment = 'crnn_lstm_synthtext'
max_string_len = model_pred.output_shape[1]
```

*For your information, the learning is going well in this situation, but there is a problem when we proceed with other tasks using this model, so we are remaking the model.*

## CHANGE

To fix this problem, I modified the transport part from transpose(1,0,2) to transpose(0,1,2) so that the dimension change of the image does not occur in this code.

```
img = cv2.imread(img_path)
                

                texts = np.copy(gt_util.text[idx])
                words = [crop_words2(img, 32, 256, True)]
                
                inputs.extend(words)
                targets.extend([texts])
            
            source_str = np.array(targets[:batch_size])
            
            images = np.ones([batch_size, width, height, num_input_channels])
            labels = -np.ones([batch_size, max_string_len])
            input_length = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
            label_length = np.zeros([batch_size, 1])
            
            for j in range(batch_size):
                images[j] = inputs[j].transpose(0,1,2)
                input_length[j,0] = max_string_len
                label_length[j,0] = len(source_str[j])
                for k, c in enumerate(source_str[j][:max_string_len]):
                    if not c in kor or c == '_':
```

And input_shape was also modified to (height, width, 1).

```
input_width = 256
input_height = 32
batch_size = 32
input_shape = (input_height, input_width, 1)

model, model_pred = CRNN(input_shape, len(kor))
experiment = 'crnn_lstm_synthtext'
max_string_len = model_pred.output_shape[1]
```

## MODEL TRANING CODE

This is my training code.

```
with open(checkdir+'/source.py','wb') as f:
    source = ''.join(['# In[%i]\n%s\n\n' % (i, In[i]) for i in range(len(In))])
    f.write(source.encode())

optimizer = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipnorm=1)

model.compile(loss={'ctc': lambda y_true, y_pred: y_pred}, optimizer=optimizer)

print("before")
model.fit_generator(generator=gen_train.generate(),
                    steps_per_epoch=gt_util_train.num_objects // batch_size,
                    epochs=1,
                    validation_data=gen_val.generate(),
                    validation_steps=gt_util_val.num_objects // batch_size,
                    callbacks=[
save_weights_only=True),
                        ModelSnapshot(checkdir, 1000),
                        Logger(checkdir)
                    ],
                    initial_epoch=0)
```

## ERROR

However, this error has occurred, and no matter how hard I try to find a solution to this error, I don't know.
Looking at the error, I think it's a resape problem, but I don't know which part to solve.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_10743/3914989167.py in <module>
     48 
     49                     ],
---> 50                     initial_epoch=0)
     51 print ("epoch time is", time_callback.times)
     52 end = datetime.datetime.now()

~/anaconda3/envs/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit_generator(self, generator, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch)
   1294         shuffle=shuffle,
   1295         initial_epoch=initial_epoch,
-> 1296         steps_name='steps_per_epoch')
   1297 
   1298   def evaluate_generator(self,

~/anaconda3/envs/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_generator.py in model_iteration(model, data, steps_per_epoch, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_data, validation_steps, validation_freq, class_weight, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, shuffle, initial_epoch, mode, batch_size, steps_name, **kwargs)
    263 
    264       is_deferred = not model._is_compiled
--> 265       batch_outs = batch_function(*batch_data)
    266       if not isinstance(batch_outs, list):
    267         batch_outs = [batch_outs]

~/anaconda3/envs/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in train_on_batch(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, reset_metrics)
   1015       self._update_sample_weight_modes(sample_weights=sample_weights)
   1016       self._make_train_function()
-> 1017       outputs = self.train_function(ins)  # pylint: disable=not-callable
   1018 
   1019     if reset_metrics:

~/anaconda3/envs/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/backend.py in __call__(self, inputs)
   3474 
   3475     fetched = self._callable_fn(*array_vals,
-> 3476                                 run_metadata=self.run_metadata)
   3477     self._call_fetch_callbacks(fetched[-len(self._fetches):])
   3478     output_structure = nest.pack_sequence_as(

~/anaconda3/envs/ocr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/client/session.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1470         ret = tf_session.TF_SessionRunCallable(self._session._session,
   1471                                                self._handle, args,
-> 1472                                                run_metadata_ptr)
   1473         if run_metadata:
   1474           proto_data = tf_session.TF_GetBuffer(run_metadata_ptr)

InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found.
  (0) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 1474560 values, but the requested shape has 98304
     [[{{node reshape_1_3/Reshape}}]]
     [[ctc_3/scan/while/ExpandDims/_745]]
  (1) Invalid argument: Input to reshape is a tensor with 1474560 values, but the requested shape has 98304
     [[{{node reshape_1_3/Reshape}}]]
0 successful operations.
0 derived errors ignored.
```

## CRNN MODEL CODE

This is my CRNN model code
If the reshape layer is a problem, is this the problem?

```
def CRNN(input_shape, num_classes, prediction_only=False, gru=False, cnn=False):
    """CRNN architecture.
    
    # Arguments
        input_shape: Shape of the input image, (32, 256, 1).
        num_classes: Number of characters in alphabet, including CTC blank.
        
    # References
        https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.05717
    """
    
    #act = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.3)
    act = 'relu'
    
    x = image_input = Input(shape=input_shape, name='image_input')
    x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv1_1')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(128, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv2_1')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='pool2')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv3_1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(256, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv3_2')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 2), padding='same', name='pool3')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv4_1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name='batchnorm1')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (3, 3), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='same', name='conv5_1')(x)
    x = BatchNormalization(name='batchnorm2')(x)
    x = MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(1, 2), padding='valid', name='pool5')(x)
    x = Conv2D(512, (2, 2), strides=(1, 1), activation=act, padding='valid', name='conv6_1')(x)
    s = x.shape
    x = Reshape((s[1],s[3]), name='reshape_1')(x)
```